# Coordinates Conversion in iPhone

Tags: iphone, coordinates

I've a list of coordinates in format ED50. The CLLocationManager class seems that works in WGS 84 (please correct me if I'm wrong).

I'm looking for a conversion formula or some class in the CL framework that can help me.

Any idea how can I make this kind of conversion?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Did you see this?

http://www.mapforums.com/ed50-wgs84-conversion-1412.html